# Как в переменную типа TObject сохранить строку?

Tags: delphi

Как правильно записать это

```
TIdContext(Clients[0]).Data := 'Client3';
```

И как потом её можно прочесть?

**upd**

пробую так, выдаёт **access violation**

```
procedure TForm1.IdTCPServer1Execute(AContext: TIdContext);
begin
  ResString := Creator.TcpResCreate(ReqString);
....

function PCreator.TcpResCreate(ClientReq : String) : String; // функция в другом юните
begin
  if login then
  begin
    if not Assigned(Form1.IdTCPServer1.Contexts) then exit;
    Clients := Form1.IdTCPServer1.Contexts.LockList;
    TIdContext(Clients[Clients.Count - 1]).Data := TStringHolder.Create(Req.sessionKey.xPlayer);
    Form1.IdTCPServer1.Contexts.UnlockList;
    Result := xxx;
....

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  TIdContext(Clients[0]).Connection.Socket.Write('message');
  IdTCPServer1.Contexts.UnlockList;
....
```

может дело в создаваемом классе?

**upd**

перестало выдавать ошибку после того как я убрал,

Clients := TLists.Create; Clients.Free;

Видимо их не надо создавать. А с классом вроде норм все.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
type
  TStringHolder = class
  private
    fValue: string;
    function GetValue: string;
  public
    constructor Create(aValue: string);
    property Value: string read GetValue write fValue;
  end;

constructor TStringHolder.Create(aValue: string);
begin
  fValue := aValue;
end;

function TStringHolder.GetValue: string;
begin
  if self <> nil then
    result := fValue
  else
    result := '';
end;
```

Записать:

```
TIdContext(IdTCPServer1.Contexts.LockList[0]).Data := TStringHolder.Create('Client3');
```

Прочитать:

```
... := TStringHolder(TIdContext(IdTCPServer1.Contexts.LockList[0]).Data).Value;
```

Не забудьте потом вызвать:

```
TIdContext(IdTCPServer1.Contexts.LockList[0]).Data.Free;
TIdContext(IdTCPServer1.Contexts.LockList[0]).Data := nil;
```

Comment: что-то проверка `self` на `nil` это костыль какой-то непонятно зачем. либо вызывающий код должен проверять данные, прежде чем кормить этому классу, либо класс должен выбросить исключение. А это затычка какая-то.

Comment: @teran Спасибо на добром слове. Это та же самая проверка, которая существует начиная с первой версии Delphi в `TObject.Free`.

Comment: дак теперь все get/set методы с такими проверками писать? nil и пустая строка это разные вещи. при работе с экземпляром нелогично проверять self на пустоту. Во free еще ладно, можно допустить. Но в delphi издавна есть много вещей, которые многим не нравятся, как глобальные переменные для форм.  зы: `getValue` в `setValue` переименовать бы  и `string` свойству добавить. и префиксы `F` общепринято заглавными делать :)

Comment: @teran "А эта грудь не слишком ли нага?"  -
 http://rvb.ru/pushkin/01text/01versus/0423_36/1829/0521.htm

Comment: @Igor Ваш класс `TStringHolder` прямо таки воняет, настолько плохой код вы написали.

Comment: @zed Спасибо за Ваше мнение. У Вас есть прекрасная возможность предложить свой вариант ответа.

Comment: @Igor А у вас есть возможность прислушаться к знающим людям и исправить свой код, а не посылать всех Пушкина читать ;)

Comment: TIdContext(IdTCPServer1.Contexts.LockList[0]).Data.Free; Это нужно делать при отключении клиента?

Comment: @ArtGrek13 - это нужно делать, когда изменяется `IdTCPServer1.Contexts.LockList[0]`, чтобы не было утечек памяти.

Comment: не понял. вот подключился клиент, я сохранил в списке его "адрес" и имя, он пересылается со мной сообщениями, синхронно, в OnExecute, дальше я ему шлю сообщение, с кнопки, он не отключается, подключается еще один по тому же алгоритму, в какой момент нужно обнулять, я так понимаю только при дисконекте клиента, я не прав?

Comment: я в вопросе дополнил как использую класс, у меня access violation выскакивает

Comment: @ArtGrek13 Я не работал с компонентой `TIdTCPServer`. На какой строчке кода ошибка?

Comment: В `GetValue` костыль, а в остальном отличное направление для решения! +1. Можно улучшить дальше, если сделать через интерфейс, там будет авто-подсчет ссылок и автоудаление.

Comment: "Можно улучшить через интерфейс," Можете показать?

Comment: @ArtGrek13 чтобы обратиться к конкретному участнику разговора, вставьте в соощение его позывной добавив спереди @

Answer (score 1):

Минуту, прежде чем мы углубимся в интерфейсы, сборку мусора и утечки памяти.

Я почитал про класс `TIdTCPServer`. У него есть свойство `ContextClass` - тип контекста, который он будет создавать. Вы можете унаследовать от `ТIdContext`, добавить свое строковое свойство, назначить `class of` Вашего наследника

```
IdTCPServer1.ContextClass = class of TMyIdContext;
```

и потом кастить `Clients[index]` к Вашему типу.

http://www.indyproject.org/docsite/html/frames.html?frmname=topic&frmfile=TIdTCPServer.html

Comment: Спасибо! почитаю